# How to deal with technologically obsolete, and therefore misleading questions?

Tags: discussion, support, old-answers

I just was researching how to correctly use MongoDB from C#. Only after a while I found out, that with V2 of the C# drivers the API completely changed. Unfortunately, there are a lot of question and answers on MongoDB out there that do not longer fit the current API.
This is very misleading and time consuming.

Would it make sense to delete such answers? Or add a Bold Warning at the top and title to mark them as obsolete?

Comment: @Thomas There are still lots of people using _obsolete_ technologies. For example there's still a good number of questions specific to [tag:turbo-c++] coming in.

Comment: I think one of the answeers in the above recommended question fits best, make ad a version note to the title or question